# Intermittent Permission Denied error when opening files from a SAMBA mount

Tags: linux, permissions, samba, network-share, mount

As mentioned above, when I attempt to open files over a SAMBA mount, sometimes it works fine and vi opens the file up, but other times vi opens up and I get an error like this:

```
"Windows/Custom2d.txt" [Permission Denied]
```

Note that it is not just vi doing this:

```
cat: Windows/Custom2d.txt: Input/output error
```

Where Windows is the linux folder name of the mount. I can mount to other Windows computers sharing folders with the same command and same sharing setup with no problems.

The following is my mounting command:

```
sudo mount -o user=<username>,uid=<username>,gid=<username>,nolinux //<Windows-IP>/temp  Windows
```

I get no errors when I mount.

The file I am opening in the example is has the following file structure:

```
c:\temp\Custom2d.txt
```

I have ensured that C:\temp is being shared and has 20 allowable simultaneous users.

This was a test to show that it does not have anything to do with recursive subfolder sharing. I have tried IP refreshing, remounting, restarting, and several different mount commands. Does anyone have any idea what could be happening?

Edit: Here is a string of commands to illustrate the issue:

```
$ cat Windows/Custom2d.txt
...
File Text
...
$ cat Windows/Custom2d.txt
cat: Windows/Custom2d.txt: Input/output error
$ cat Windows/Custom2d.txt
cat: Windows/Custom2d.txt: Input/output error
$ cat Windows/Custom2d.txt
cat: Windows/Custom2d.txt: Input/output error
```

Comment: Based on the fact that other computers work just fine, I would suspect that the problematic machine either has network issues (possibly just congestion) or that the system is too busy to respond in due time. So the first place to look would be the device manager of that windows machine. Mainly look for CPU load, paging, and network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

The following solved my issue:

A known Windows 7 bug that causes "mount error(12): cannot allocate memory" on an otherwise perfect cifs share on the Linux end can be fixed by setting a few registry keys on the Windows box as follows:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\LargeSystemCache (set to 1)

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\Size (set to 3)
```

From: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Samba